# Is python flet fully functional to create cross platform app for both Android and iOS and can it will be published on playstore

Tags: python, flet

Is python flet fully operational ready for production and those app made by flet, can it will get published on play store and ios store

I am python programmers and I want to learn cross mobile app development as well. I heard about new framework called python flet which is new. I want to know, is that framework is fully functional and has scope in future.